# iOS In-App pucrhase: Handle prorating of plan while switching

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

How can I handle In-App SaaS plan upgrade (from paid plan A -> paid plan B.)  How do you handle pro-rating and switching of subscription?

There is a paid plan A for $9.99/month and a paid plan B for $19.99/month.

The user has a free account and then upgrades via an In-App subscription to Plan A.  The user loves Plan A so much that they want to upgrade to Plan B two days later.  How do you handle this with In-App purchases?

Answer (score 5):

You don't.

The Apple-supplied in-app purchasing system does not provide a way to pro-rate a purchase. There is no way to do a refund, and there is no way for a vendor (you) to do a cancellation.

Also be careful, if you implement plan A and plan B as separate subscriptions... a user who signs up for plan B *after* signing up for plan A will very likely be signed up for both. They will need to cancel their subscription to plan A.

In general, the in-app purchasing system is not well suited for tiered offerings such as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Apple new subscription system https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/ now provides downgrade/upgrade/crossgrade capabilities.